# Object fit en outlook

Tags: html, css, email

Estoy usando la propiedad css object-fit:cover; para un boletín de correo electrónico, outlook quita esta propiedad ¿Como la puedo usar?

No puedo usar la imagen como fondo del div me la piden como imagen a parte. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo cierto es que **no es posible usar esa propiedad en los clientes de correo**, tampoco hay una forma emular esta propiedad de forma práctica o igual, ya que por motivos de seguridad muchos de estos, bloquean muchas características de html5 y css3.

Te recomiendo mirar esta [lista de compatibilidad técnica en diseño de mailing](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/), publicada por MailChimp para asegurarte que puedes o no usar, si la propiedad o elemento que buscas no está en la lista, es que no lo puedes usar.

Lo mejor es que uses un framework como [ink](https://zurb.com/ink/index.php) de foundation o [emailframe.work](http://emailframe.work/). Ahora, **si tienes un conocimiento mínimo en maquetación html y css, lo mejor es que aprendas a usar tablas para maquetar** (en email aún está vigente, aunque ahora sea una malisima práctica para la web) o descargar alguna plantilla de correo y modificarla.

Comment: Estoy usando el diseño como tabla, lo que sucede es que tengo un td que mide 284x250 la foto de fondo es de 1800x1100 entonces al ponerla en este td la reduce y se ve como si estuviera estirada y espichada, por esta razon use el object-fit: cover; no sabes de casualidad que otra propiedad puedo usar parecida a esta?

Comment: No la hay, como te digo en la lista de compatibilidad son las que son, ni una más ni una menos. Lo que te recomiendo es que adaptes la foto al tamaño final, porque igual no tiene sentido (por peso y dimensiones) hacer ese reajuste por código en un correo.